# Find name of directories that don't contain an specific subdirectory

Tags: find, directory, plugin, wordpress

I have more than 200 wordpress sites under `/home2/blogname/public_html/` and I need to find what of these blogs don't have one subdir inside called "better-wp-security" under de plugins dir like: `/home2/blogname/public_html/wp-content/plugins/`

The reason is to know what blogs don't have the plugin "better-wp-security" for install it

Blogs that have the dir will show something like this:

```
/home2/blogname/public_html/wp-content/plugins/better-wp-security/
```

...so I need to list main dirs of blogs (`/home2/blogname`/) that don't have that directory.

How can I do that?.

Comment: Maybe `find -type d /home2/*/public_html/wp-content/plugins/better-wp-security/` works?

Comment: Then compare with a list of everything to get the list of which weren't found by the first command.

Comment: Might want to `sed` out subdirectories of the plugin. Hope that helped.

Comment: did not work properly. Listed tons of subdirs inside each /home2/*/public_html/wp-content/plugins/better-wp-security/. I need something like this:

find /home2/*/public_html/wp-content/plugins/better-wp-security/ -type d | grep --invert-match /better-wp-security/

previous command don't work either :(

Comment: My third comment was about `sed`'ing out subdirectories - by the name of slashes. I know it's surely not the most elegant way, but I think it should provide at least a quick way to get it done.

Comment: You would want to `sort` each of the lists before finding out the lines not matching the two lists. I don't remember what would be the last command, but should be an easy search in Stack Exchange. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with `find`, but you could also use a shell loop:

```
for dir in /home2/blogname/*
do
  [ -d "$dir"/public_html/wp-content/plugins/better-wp-security ] || printf '%s is missing a public_html/wp-content/plugins/better-wp-security directory\n' "$dir"
done
```

With GNU find:

```
find /home2/blogname -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec sh -c \
  'test ! -d "$1"/public_html/wp-content/plugins/better-wp-security' findsh {} \; -print
```

This runs a small shell snippet on every entry under /home2/blogname -- beyond /home2/blogname itself, given `-mindepth 1`, and not on any subdirectories of /home2/blogname/*, given `-maxdepth 1`. The snippet checks to see whether the given directory has the listed subdirectory structure; if it does not, it passes the `test` and so is printed.

Comment: both solutions worked like a charm. Thank you everyone for all the help!! ^^